# Is there a way to simplify the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{a}{b^n}=\frac{a}{(\lvert b\rvert-1)\frac{1}{b}\lvert b\rvert}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb R:\lvert b\rvert\gt1\rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{a}{b^n}=\frac{a}{(\lvert b\rvert-1)\frac{1}{b}\lvert b\rvert}$$

If $b$ is restricted to be non-negative, the expression simplifies to
$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb R:b\gt1\rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{a}{b^n}=\frac{a}{b-1}$$
The denominator $(\lvert b\rvert-1)\frac{1}{b}\lvert b\rvert$ from the right-hand side of the identity in the first expression is the only way I could come up with that preserves $b$'s sign when it is negative. This is the part I'm trying to simplify.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I guess you want sums starting at $n=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure the identity holds if the sum starts at $n=0$, i think i would have to add $+a$ to the whole right-hand side wouldn't I?

Comment: For negative $b$, your right expression simplifies to $\frac{a}{b+1}$ , when in fact the sum equals $\frac{a}{b-1}$ for any such $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the standard geometric series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}\qquad (|x|\lt1)$$
We have that your result is just
$$\frac{a}b\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1/b)^n=\frac{\frac{a}b}{1-\frac1{b}}=\frac{a}{b-1}\qquad(|b|\gt1)$$which is also valid for negative $b$.